# Calling url to open by text string

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, scanning

Ok so im making an app that involve a qr scanner on result i have text showing with the url of the code is there any way in an onclick listener to call the text from the result and open it in the browser if so how can I do it

Java Snippet

```
    Button browser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ulibutton);
        browser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url = new URL(
                        getString(R.string.contents_text)));

                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        ImageView barcodeImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.barcode_image_view);
        if (barcode == null) {
            barcodeImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    getResources(), R.drawable.icon));
        } else {
            barcodeImageView.setImageBitmap(barcode);
        }

        TextView formatTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.format_text_view);
        formatTextView.setText(rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

        TextView typeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type_text_view);
        typeTextView.setText(resultHandler.getType().toString());

        DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,
                DateFormat.SHORT);
        String formattedTime = formatter.format(new Date(rawResult
                .getTimestamp()));
        TextView timeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_text_view);
        timeTextView.setText(formattedTime);

        TextView metaTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meta_text_view);
        View metaTextViewLabel = findViewById(R.id.meta_text_view_label);
        metaTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        metaTextViewLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Map<ResultMetadataType, Object> metadata = rawResult
                .getResultMetadata();
        if (metadata != null) {
            StringBuilder metadataText = new StringBuilder(20);
            for (Map.Entry<ResultMetadataType, Object> entry : metadata
                    .entrySet()) {
                if (DISPLAYABLE_METADATA_TYPES.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                    metadataText.append(entry.getValue()).append('\n');
                }
            }
            if (metadataText.length() > 0) {
                metadataText.setLength(metadataText.length() - 1);
                metaTextView.setText(metadataText);
                metaTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                metaTextViewLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        TextView contentsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contents_text_view);
        contentsTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        CharSequence displayContents = resultHandler.getDisplayContents();
        contentsTextView.setText(displayContents);
        // Crudely scale betweeen 22 and 32 -- bigger font for shorter text
        int scaledSize = Math.max(22, 32 - displayContents.length() / 4);
        contentsTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, scaledSize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(YourUrl)));
 startActivity(i);
```